# Bad connection response to long-running MSSQL transaction in Golang

Tags: sql-server, go, azure-sql-database

I have a requester that manages my SQL queries against an Azure SQL database. The function responsible for transaction queries is as follows:

```
import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/cenkalti/backoff"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb" // Need to import the SQL driver so we can tell Golang how to interpret our requests
)

// Helper function that does a single Exec with a transaction with a context on a query and variables.
// This function will return an error if there are any failures
func (requester *Requester) doTransaction(ctx context.Context, 
    isolation sql.IsolationLevel, txFunc func(*sql.Tx) error) error {

    // First, get the database connection; if this fails then return an error
    conn, err := requester.getConn(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Before we continue on, ensure that the connection is clsoed and returned to the connection pool
    defer func() {
        if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Close failed, error: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    // Next, start the transaction with the given context and the default isolation
    tx, err := requester.getTx(ctx, conn, isolation)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Now, ensure that the transaction is either rolled back or committed before
    // the function ends
    var tErr error
    defer func() {
        if p := recover(); p != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            panic(p)
        } else if tErr != nil {
            log.Printf("An error occurred: %v", tErr)
            if err := tx.Rollback(); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Rollback failed, error: %v", err)
            }
        } else {
            if tErr := tx.Commit(); tErr != nil {
                log.Printf("Commit failed, error: %v", tErr)
            }
        }
    }()

    // Finally, run the function and return the result
    tErr = txFunc(tx)
    return tErr
}

// Helper function that gets a connection to the database with a backup and retry
func (requester *Requester) getConn(ctx context.Context) (*sql.Conn, error) {

    // Create an object that will dictate how and when the retries are done
    // We currently want an exponential backoff that retries a maximum of 5 times
    repeater := backoff.WithContext(backoff.WithMaxRetries(
        backoff.NewExponentialBackOff(), 5), ctx)

    // Do a retry operation with a 500ms wait time and a maximum of 5 retries
    // and return the result of the operation therein
    var conn *sql.Conn
    if err := backoff.Retry(func() error {

        // Attempt to get the connection to the database
        var err error
        if conn, err = requester.conn.Conn(ctx); err != nil {

            // We failed to get the connection; if we have a login error, an EOF or handshake
            // failure then we'll attempt the connection again later so just return it and let
            // the backoff code handle it
            log.Printf("Conn failed, error: %v", err)
            if isLoginError(err, requester.serverName, requester.databaseName) {
                return err
            } else if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "EOF") {
                return err
            } else if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "TLS Handshake failed") {
                return err
            }

            // Otherwise, we can't recover from the error so return it
            return backoff.Permanent(err)
        }

        return nil
    }, repeater); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return conn, nil
}

// Helper function that starts a transaction against the database
func (requester *Requester) getTx(ctx context.Context, conn *sql.Conn, 
    isolation sql.IsolationLevel) (*sql.Tx, error) {

    // Create an object that will dictate how and when the retries are done
    // We currently want an exponential backoff that retries a maximum of 5 times
    repeater := backoff.WithContext(backoff.WithMaxRetries(
        backoff.NewExponentialBackOff(), 5), ctx)

    // Do a retry operation with a 500ms wait time and a maximum of 5 retries
    // and return the result of the operation therein
    var tx *sql.Tx
    if err := backoff.Retry(func() error {

        // Attempt to start the transaction with the given context and the default isolation
        var err error
        if tx, err = conn.BeginTx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: isolation, ReadOnly: false}); err != nil {

            // We failed to create the transaction; if we have a connection error then we'll
            // attempt the connection again later so just return it and let the backoff code handle it
            if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.") || 
                strings.Contains(err.Error(), "bad connection") {
                log.Printf("BeginTx failed, error: %v. Retrying...", err)
                return err
            }

            // Otherwise, we can't recover from the error so return it
            log.Printf("Unknown/uncaught exception when attempting to create a transaction, error: %v", err)
            return backoff.Permanent(err)
        }

        return nil
    }, repeater); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return tx, nil
}
```

The requester object wraps an `sql.Db` and is created like this:

```
// First, create a connection string from the endpoint, port, user name, password and database name
connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%s;database=%s;connection timeout=30",
    endpoint, dbUser, dbPassword, port, dbName)

// Finally, attempt to connect to the database. If this fails then return an error
db, err := sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// Ensure that our connections are used and reused in such a way
// as to avoid bad connections and I/O timeouts
db.SetMaxOpenConns(20)
db.SetConnMaxLifetime(10 * time.Minute)
db.SetConnMaxIdleTime(10 * time.Minute)
```

On the whole this works well. The one problem I've noticed is that, when a long time has elapsed between individual requests, then I'll get an `i/o timeout` error on the first retry and then `bad connection` errors on subsequent retries, ultimately resulting in failure. My thought is that the problem is related to [this bug](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/328). Essentially, it appears that Microsoft invalidates idle requests after 30 minutes. However, as I have the maximum idle time set to 10 minutes, this shouldn't be the problem.

What's going on here and how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I discovered that the database connection grows stale after a 30 minute window, and modifying the lifetime or idle time of the connection pool doesn't really do anything to fix that. So, what I did to alleviate this problem was to modify my `getConn` function to ping the server beforehand so I could ensure that the connection is "fresh", for lack of a better term.

```
func (requester *Requester) getConn(ctx context.Context) (*sql.Conn, error) {

    // First, attempt to ping the server to ensure that the connection is good
    // If this fails, then return an error
    if err := requester.conn.PingContext(ctx); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create an object that will dictate how and when the retries are done
    // We currently want an exponential backoff that retries a maximum of 5 times
    repeater := backoff.WithContext(backoff.WithMaxRetries(
        backoff.NewExponentialBackOff(), 5), ctx)

    // Do a retry operation with a 500ms wait time and a maximum of 5 retries
    // and return the result of the operation therein
    var conn *sql.Conn
    if err := backoff.Retry(func() error {

        // Attempt to get the connection to the database
        var err error
        if conn, err = requester.conn.Conn(ctx); err != nil {

            // We failed to get the connection; if we have a login error, an EOF or handshake
            // failure then we'll attempt the connection again later so just return it and let
            // the backoff code handle it
            log.Printf("Conn failed, error: %v", err)
            if isLoginError(err, requester.serverName, requester.databaseName) {
                return err
            } else if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "EOF") {
                return err
            } else if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "TLS Handshake failed") {
                return err
            }

            // Otherwise, we can't recover from the error so return it
            return backoff.Permanent(err)
        }

        return nil
    }, repeater); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return conn, nil
}
```